# Android PHP connection error when reading query

Tags: php, android, mysql, database

I am trying to save values taken from Android app and put theminto a database on  local server but I am still receiving empty toast while adding data to database. I have checked it and it seems that my script stops working when it reads query
(see comments in php script). I really dont know how to force this to insert data
Thanks in Advance

Android code:

```
public class CreateConnectionClass {
 String sendPostRequest(String requestURL,HashMap<String,String> postDataParams){
    URL url;
    String response = "";
    try{
        url = new URL(requestURL);

        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(150000);
        httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(150000);
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
        bufferedWriter.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

        bufferedWriter.flush();
        bufferedWriter.close();
        outputStream.close();
        int responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
        if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
            response = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }
        else{
            response = "Error Registering";
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}

private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String,String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : params.entrySet()){
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

}

php code:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
echo 'inside'; // this one appears in android app toast 
require_once('connectvars.php');
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
    or die('No connection');
$user_login = $_POST["user_login"];
$user_password = $_POST["user_password"];
$user_phonenumber = $_POST["user_phonenumber"];
$user_email = $_POST["user_email"];
echo' '.$user_login.','.$user_password.','.$user_phonenumber.','.$user_email.'';
if(!empty($user_login) && !empty($user_password) && !empty($user_phonenumber) && !empty($user_email)){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user_db WHERE user_login = '$user_login' OR user_email = 'user_email' OR user_phonenumber = '$user_phonenumber' ";
    $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($dbc,$sql));
    echo 'inside'; // here i recicve only </br> in toast and no data and everything stops
    if(isset($check)){
        echo 'username , email or phone number already exist';

    }
    else{
        $query = "INSERT INTO user_db (user_login,user_password,user_phonenumber,user_email)".
            "VALUES('$user_login','$user_password','$user_phonenumber','$user_email')";
            if(mysql_query($dbc,$query)){
                echo 'sucessfully registered';
            }
            else{
                echo 'try again';
            }
    }
    mysqli_close($dbc);
}
else{
    echo 'error';
}
echo 'err,'
}
?>
```

I am using vamp server and connecting from app to script with

```
 private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://192.168.1.5/webapp/register.php";
```

Comment: check the errors.. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and pass it to your response. And don't mix mysql and mysqli functions!! mysqli is way to go..

Comment: does this line return result in your app - echo' '.$user_login.','.$user_password.','.$user_phonenumber.','.$user_email.'';?

Comment: how to check mysqli_error ?. I am trying to display it but nothing shows ? (quite new with php and servers ).   @NollyJ  The line you asking  returns correct datas

Answer (score 0):

Ok , it's working . There were some errors with php script. 
Corrected php :

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

require_once('connectvars.php');
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
    or die('Brak połączenia z serewrem MySQL');
$user_login = $_POST["user_login"];
$user_password = $_POST["user_password"];
$user_phonenumber = $_POST["user_phonenumber"];
$user_email = $_POST["user_email"];

if(!empty($user_login) && !empty($user_password) && !empty($user_phonenumber) && !empty($user_email)){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user_db WHERE user_login = '$user_login' OR user_email = 'user_email' OR user_phonenumber = '$user_phonenumber' ";
    $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($dbc,$query));
    //echo 'inside';
    if(isset($check)){
    echo 'username , email or phone number already exist';
}
else{
        $query = "INSERT INTO user_db (join_date,user_login,user_password,user_phonenumber,user_email)".
            "VALUES(NOW(),'$user_login','$user_password','$user_phonenumber','$user_email')";
        mysqli_query($dbc,$query)
            or die('Error with database');
        echo 'sucessfully registered';
    }
    }
    mysqli_close($dbc);
}
else{
     echo 'error';
}
?>
```

Also change one line in android file

```
if(responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK){ // Here HttpsURL... instead of HttpURL
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
            response = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }
```